# Synaptic package manager not working for a ubuntu guest on virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I recently installed virtualbox on Windows7 and my guest operating system is Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx).

My internet works fine but the rest of the applications that require network access like Synaptic, Ubuntu Software sources, Pidgin wont work and show Network Access Error or Specifically :
"Failed to access files. Check your Internet Connection."

I have used various methods listed on help forums but none have been helpful enough. I feel that the problem lies in setting up of my "NETWORK PROXY".
I am using a WI-FI Network to connect to internet and probably my WIFI network on guest is not defined/setup properly.

Any Help or Suggestions?

Comment: You internet works fine where? Within the guest OS? Or on your host OS? Two different environments, you know...

Comment: yeah it works fine within the guest when i use a browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I tried a lot going on my intuition it turns out i was searching along the right path.
Apparently yu have to set up a DNS server on your guest machine that corresponds to your host.
For more detailed solution please refer :
http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=2430

Note: This solution is for users who have a NAT connection adapter between guest and host.